# Rspec/Capybara complaning about application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

When attempting to visit a page using Capybara and Rspec, I get the following error:

**The error**:

```
 Failure/Error: visit login_path
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "= require boots..."
     (in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

**The file** (/app/assets/stylesheets/**application.css**):

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
*= require bootstrap.min
```

This code was generated by the twitter bootstrap rails generators provided by the gem, and as far as I know, the syntax is correct. Why is it complaining?

Comment: Your `*= require bootstrap.min` should be inside the closing comment marker `*/`.

Comment: Really? I wouldn't expect such a widespread bundle like Bootstrap to make this mistake, but thanks for clearing it up. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it!